# What does it mean signature algorithm: itu-t?

Tags: c#, security, openssl, x509certificate

I have an unsigned pem certificate.
when I use openssl to view the certificate I get signature algorithm: itu-t (using x509Certificate I get 0.0)

what does it mean itu-t?
I know that the certificate is not signed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In X.509, "objects" are identified by Object Identifiers (OIDs). `0.0` is probably just used as a placeholder OID, which happens to corresponds to [itu-t](http://www.oid-info.com/get/0.0).

You can browse this OID (and others) at http://www.oid-info.com/get/0.0

When the cert is signed it should have a proper signature algorithm OID, such as

- sha1WithRSAEncryption: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.5](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.113549.1.1.5)
- ecdsa-with-SHA1: [1.2.840.10045.4.1](http://oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.10045.4.1)
- and so on...

The reason that "itu-t" is there is because OIDs were supposed to be allocated hierarchically, corresponding to various standards bodies or organizations. For example,

- 0 = itu-t
- 1 = iso
- 1.2.840.113549 = RSA Data Security

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and references! :)

Comment: i know it has been a long time since you gave this answer, but i hope you might be able to help.
we've upgraded openssl (to 1.1.1b) and now our existing code refuses to sign  CRSs with itu-t.
is there a way to make it sign a CSR with itu-t?
we need it for our internal communications processes, nothing public